# Gulp 3 - Makes js files 3 times bigger then normal files

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

Having a problem with a gulp and js file minifications, gulp makes 3 times bigger files.

For example lightgallery.min.js - **49kb** (downloaded from GitHub) then I download the same file via npm and required in js file (same if I insert downloaded file content from github)

```
global.lightgallery = require('lightgallery');
```

and run gulp it makes file **133kb**

GULP TASK

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src( SOURCEPATHS.jsSource )
        .pipe( browserify() )
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( rename({ extname: '.min.js' }) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(APPPATH.js) );
});
```

Not using any sourcemaps.

Maybe someone was having the same problem?

Comment: I see you're not passing any options to `uglify`. Files can be made even lighter after being processed by `uglify` by passing options - full list [here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options)

Comment: Does it combine multiple js-files, what is the value of `SOURCEPATHS.jsSource`?

Comment: It's not combining multiple js files into one

    var SOURCEPATHS = { sassSource : 'src/scss/**/*.scss',  jsSource: 'src/js/*.js',
    imgSource   : 'src/img/**'} @lofihelsinki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `lightgallery` has a dependency of jQuery as specified [on the npm description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightgallery) and in [its package.json](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/blob/master/package.json). When Browserify does its thing, it checks the dependency graph of the package and pulls everything in. jQuery v3.3.1 minified is around **~85kb** which should account for the discrepancy.

In case you already have jQuery somewhere else, you can usually get Browserify to ignore that particular package. For example, using the `gulp-browserify` package:

```
.pipe(browserify({ ignore: 'jquery' }))
```

**Update**

You can selectively apply this to files using the [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) plugin:

```
.pipe(
    gulpif(
        'jquery.js',
        browserify(),
        browserify({ ignore: ['jquery'] })
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but now my jquery was not inserted its ignore my jquery.js file. Is it possible to not ignore one file?

Comment: To confirm: you have a `jquery.js` file in your application (that isn't pulled in via npm) and Browserify is ignoring it only when you add in the `{ ignore: 'jquery' }` option?

Comment: I have jquery required in jquery.js file pulled from npm, but now it's ignoring. Is it possible to let throw jquery.js file from ignoring?

Comment: interesting is let throw and generate normal jquery file with all content, but it's not working console throws error `TypeError: jQuery.fn is undefined` and other js files don't work `TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: Deleted my previous comment of using `.pipe(browserify({ ignore: ['jquery'] })).on('prebundle', function(bundle) {bundle.require('jquery');})` as I didn't think it would do exactly what you wanted. I'm assuming that it outputted a bundled jQuery file with an empty module in it. I've added in an update to my answer which involves an extra plugin `gulp-if` but should achieve what you're looking to do in applying a different config to one file than to the others.

Comment: Ok so I just make testing I this code it not working correctly, then I add some scripts for example lightgallery.js or slick.js via npm it's allways showing error and scripts not working `TypeError: p.fn is undefined` or `TypeError: d.fn is undefined` if I remove `{ ignore: ['jquery'] }` working good.